# why the address of the pointer and pointer value are different at C

Tags: c, pointers

i create ptr pointer and set it to adress of x then print both of the adress why they are different each other ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int *ptr;
    int x = 20;
    ptr = &x;
    printf("adress of x = %p\n", &x);
    printf("adress ptr = %p\n", &ptr);
}
```

Output :

```
adress of x = 0x7ffe31da2274
adress of ptr = 0x7ffe31da2278
```

Comment: its a pointer to a pointer -`&ptr` is the address of `ptr` itself

Comment: why wouldn't they be? why do you expect them to be the same?

Comment: A pointer is a variable by itself. It's value is contained at some memory location. That memory location has an address, which might be different than the value.

Comment: `&x` is the address of `x`. `&ptr` is the address of `ptr`, not the address of `x`.

Comment: A loose analogy: `x` is your car in a parking garage. It is parked in row 5, slot 6 (i.e. `&x` -- where is `x` parked/located?). `ptr` is your parking ticket/stub. It has "row 5, slot 6" written on it. `&ptr` means "where is your _ticket/stub_ now?" (i.e. _not_ "where is your car parked?"). Since you just entered the parking garage, and you are holding your parking stub, you can say (e.g.) `&ptr` is row 0, slot 0 (i.e. the door).

Comment: thanks everyone i missunderstand address of operator wrong i got perfectly now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `&x` produces the address of `x`.
- `&ptr` produces the address of `ptr`.
- `ptr` produces the address stored in `ptr`, i.e. the address of `x`.

The addresses of `x` and `ptr` are obviously going to be different, since different values are stored in each (the number `20` in `x`, and the address of `x` in `ptr`), as illustrated by the following memory layout:

```
int x            int* ptr
@ 0x1008         @ 0x1000          <-- Some made up addresses.
+-----------+    +-----------+
|        20 |    |    0x1008 |     <-- What's stored there.
+-----------+    +-----------+
```

If you want the value stored in `ptr` (the address of `x`), simply use `ptr`.

```c
printf( "address of x   = %p\n", (void*)&x   );  // 0x1008
printf( "address of ptr = %p\n", (void*)&ptr );  // 0x1000
printf( "address in ptr = %p\n", (void*)ptr  );  // 0x1008
```

Answer (score 2):

To make it simpler, lets draw it out:

```
+------+      +----------+      +---+
| &ptr | ---> | ptr (&x) | ---> | x |
+------+      +----------+      +---+
```

This is basically how pointers and the pointer-to operator `&` works. A pointer really points to something else.

So you have the variable `x`. Then you make the variable `ptr` point to `x`. And then you use `&ptr` to get a pointer to the variable `ptr`.

The type of `x` is `int`. The type of `ptr` is `int *`. And the type of `&ptr` is `int **`.

Now, to get the value that `ptr` is pointing to you need to use the dereference operator `*`. As in `*ptr`. By applying the pointer-to operator `&` we go to the left in the image, and by applying the dereference operator `*` we follow the arrow to where it points.

Comment: Re "*To make it simpler, lets draw it out:*", Why are there three boxes??? There are only two values stored.